# How to install Windows 8 as a dual boot with Linux Mint pre installed?

Tags: linux, installation, windows-8-preview, linux-mint

I have Linux Mint installed on my system. Now I want to install Windows 8 OS on another drive which is empty, so how can I achieve that.

Does installing Windows over Linux affect GRUB loader?

PS: Don't want to do it the virtual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, Windows installation destroys GRUB, but you should be able to boot Linux from CD/DVD after Win8 installation and Linux should be able to **recover GRUB easily** ([this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) method works for Mint as well) and I believe it might be the simplest solution.